# Очистить текст от цифр/чисел. Реализация на Python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, natasha

*Мне необходимо опционально очистить текст от цифр/чисел. 
Реализовать нужно с помощью  **Python**. 
Например, дан текст:*

```
"Мой дядя проживет по адресу улица Липатова дом 6, квартира 15.
Он родился 15 мая 1970 г. Его зарплата составляет 300 долларов. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте ".
```

На выходе должен получиться такой текст:

```
"Мой дядя проживет по адресу .
Он родился  Его зарплата составляет . Каждый месяц он откладывает по тысяч мне на учебу в институте "
```

*Решила реализовать эту задачу с помощью библиотеки **Natasha**.*. Но там недостаточно функционала (либо я что-то не так делаю). Мой код:

```
from natasha import (
    DatesExtractor,
    AddressExtractor,
    MoneyExtractor,
)
from natasha.markup import show_markup

extractors = [
    DatesExtractor(),
    AddressExtractor(),
    MoneyExtractor(),
]

text = '''
Мой дядя проживет по адресу улица Липатова дом 6, квартира 15.
Он родился 15 мая 1970 г. Его зарплата составляет 300 долларов. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте 
'''

spans = []
    for extractor in extractors:
    matches = extractor(text)
    spans.extend(_.span for _ in matches)
text = show_markup(text, spans)
```

Выводит:

```
Мой дядя проживет по адресу [[улица Липатова дом 6, квартира 15]].
Он родился [[15 мая 1970 г.]] Его зарплата составляет [[300 долларов]]. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте
```

Из этого следуют вопросы:

- как удалить то, что находится в квадратных скобках? (Пример: [[15 мая 1970 г.]])
- как удалить прописные цифры? (Пример: один, двадцать шесть и т.д.)

Comment: А почему у вас в примере как должно быть от "десять тысяч" осталось "тысяч", ведь это тоже число?

Comment: Почему исчезли слова "улица Липатова"? Это цифра или число?

Comment: На счет тысяч я не уверена, что оно должно остаться.

Comment: Улицу, дом и прочее сама библиотека Natasha убирает

Comment: @ГалинаПеревалова при чем здесь "тысяч" - если десять тысяч - это число? В этом уверен любой пользователь на ruSO, кроме вас)))

Comment: точно точно, затупила

Comment: Я боюсь ваша Наташа недоразвитая какая-то библиотека. Ну предположим будет в тексте прописное число **два миллиона двести пятьдесят восемь тысяч шестьсот двадцать один** . А Наташа подумает что "тысяч" это не число, а может и на миллионы забьёт...)

Comment: Ну короче вам надо в вашу Наташу вписать все цифры, один, два, три, двадцать, и так далее до n. Ну, естессно по падежам, ну и всё будет работать, А может уже кто-то вписал)

Comment: она даже на "десять тысяч" не реагирует))

Comment: Она со своей задачей неплохо справляется, но прописные числа это не для нее

Comment: прочитал на хабре статью, ну, желаю вам успехов в освоении Yargy. После Yargy Наташка станет более умной и сможет всё! )))

Answer (score 3):

Возможно **natasha** смогла бы это сделать, но с ней не работал, поэтому предлагаю решение из коробки (просто удалим последовательности `[[...]]`):

```
text = """\
Мой дядя проживет по адресу [[улица Липатова дом 6, квартира 15]].
Он родился [[15 мая 1970 г.]] Его зарплата составляет [[300 долларов]]. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте 
"""

import re
new_text = re.sub(r'\[\[.+?\]\]', '', text)
print(new_text)
```

Консоль:

```
Мой дядя проживет по адресу .
Он родился  Его зарплата составляет . Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте
```

Comment: У вас осталось "десять") Как у меня в принципе. Но это решается с помощью ``re.sub(r'десять', ...`` и так много раз для любого прописного числа. Наверн.

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist оставлю обработку `десять` и прочих строк на Наташу :)

Comment: Мы только что  в комментах поняли, что Наташе надо оставить не десять, а десять тысяч)))

Comment: С помощью регулярных выражений пробовала. Можно ли сделать как-то, чтобы не создавать новый проект, а все в одной куче, и выделить и удалить?

Comment: @ГалинаПеревалова, а про какой проект вы говорите? Этот пример с регуляркой нужен для постобработки после Наташи. Мне кажется вам нужно покопать в сторону Наташи, чтобы разобраться почему "десять тысяч" не обработало :) В этой статье https://habr.com/post/349864/ есть пример с `восемь тысяч` который обработался

Comment: В той статье [[8 000 (восемь тысяч) рублей 00]] из-за цифр так обработалось, если их убрать, то Наташа эти тысячи не видит

Answer (score 1):

В интерактивном режиме это делается так:

```
>>> s = 'Hi, my father live in Moscow, Novoslobodskaya st. 65. lit. 4'
>>> result = ''.join([i for i in s if not i.isdigit()])
>>> result
'Hi, my father live in Moscow, Novoslobodskaya st. . lit. '
>>>
```

Использовал английский текст, так как с русские символы  не печатает. Я не понимаю  в путхоне.

Либо же можете использовать любой из этих вариантов:

---

```
result = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', s)
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> output = re.sub(r'\d+', '', 'Мой дядя проживет по адресу улица Липатова дом 6, квартира 15.Он родился 15 мая 1970 г. Его зарплата составляет 300 долларов. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте')
>>> print output
Мой дядя проживет по адресу улица Липатова дом , квартира .Он родился  мая  г. Его зарплата составляет  долларов. Каждый месяц он откладывает по десять тысяч мне на учебу в институте
>>>
```

---

А вот как удалить прописные цифры - это другой вопрос, и наверняка нужен какой-то массив с прописными цифрами для сравнения с текстом, я не знаю, наверное. Но не уверен.

Comment: А `isalpha()` пробельные символы, специальные символы, кириллицу и т.п. поддерживает? :)

Comment: Не знаю, не шарю. Просто загуглил.)

Comment: Да, пожалуй надо выпилить))

Comment: просто числа удалить не подойдет. Нужно, чтобы адрес или дата полностью удалялись

Comment: @ГалинаПеревалова: *Мне необходимо опционально очистить текст от цифр/чисел.*

Comment: Так была задача поставлена передо мной. Я ниже пояснила, что нужно)

Comment: Да, я потом увидел, тупанул, сорри. @gil9red в таком случае заслуживает от меня плюс!

Answer (score -3):

Как вариант, можно использовать метод `replace`, заменив все вхождения цифр и слов названий цифр на пустую строку.

`text = text.replcae("0","").replcae("1","").replcae("2","").replcae("3","")` и так далее

Или занести все удаляемые символы/слова в массив и вызвать replace в цикле.

Comment: Хоть бы кто объяснил, почему этот метод плох настолько, что стоит минусы ставить

Comment: не знаю, тупость, я плюсанул, как по мне, так самое оптимальное